# Accessing padding from stylesheet in QT

Tags: css, qt, qt4, stylesheet

I have a custom QWidget subclass that lays out a number of children. In my stylesheet I define a background, which works fine. I also define padding, which doesn't work. I clearly need to provide support for this myself.

To do that, I need to be able to find out what padding is set in the stylesheet for my widget. I do not wish to parse the stylesheet myself, that would not make much sense. How can I access the top, left, bottom and right padding set in the stylesheet?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your custom widget has to inherit from a widget that supports the "box model" (you can find which widgets do on [that page](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet-reference.html)), and then you can use `QWidget::contentsRect()` to get the... content rectangle :

[image: Qt Box Model]

Comment: Correct, QWidget itself doesn't support box model. Use QFrame instead.